# Azure ML Notebook: Tensorflow does not detect CUDA GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am creating an ML pipeline using Microsoft's Azure Notebooks. I have been having a lot of trouble using CUDA with Tensorflow, I just cannot seem to connect it to the GPU. The problem is that:

`tf.test.gpu_device_name()` returns `''`

Even if all other indicators seem to be indicate that a GPU is present and that everything is installed successfully:
`tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()` returns `true`

`!nvcc --version` returns

```
    nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
    Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
    Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
    Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

`!nvidia-smi` returns

````
Wed Jun 16 08:47:01 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.19.01    Driver Version: 465.19.01    CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA Tesla K80    On   | 00000001:00:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P8    34W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+```
````

I am using CUDA v 11.2 and Tensorflow v 1.15.2.
I was able to make this work easily in other cloud GPU service providers such as Colab and Paperspace.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) for `Tensorflow 1.15.0` the compatible `CUDA` version is `10`.

Due to incompatibility between them, you get `''` when you have tried with `tf.test.gpu_device_name()`.

Above issue can be resolved either by upgrade Tensorflow or downgrade CUDA driver as per tested build configurations

[image]